# ASP.NET MVC Core DateTime format using jQuery DateTimePicker

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core-mvc, datetimepicker, datetime-format

I have an ASP.NET Core MVC application with a view model which has a DateTime property for "Date of Birth":

```
[Required]
public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
```

I want to let the user to pick/enter date in dd/mm/yyyy format.

In the view originally I was using html Date type and it was working fine in Chrome but some issues in Edge and not working in IE 11 at all. Therefore I have decided to replace it with the jQuery DatePicker:

```
<input class="form-control datepicker" name="DateOfBirth" type="text" required>
```

In Js file:

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
```

It all works fine as long as I pass value as mm/dd/yyyy format (12/12/2017). As soon as I change it to 13/12/2017 (dd/mm/yyyy) I get server side error saying that method arguments are not valid.

Comment: You need to change the culture on the server to one that accepts dates in `dd/MM/yyyy` format (or you need to create a custom ModelBinder to convert the dates to your format

Comment: How to change culture on the server in asp net core?

Comment: In your `web.config` file, in the `<system.web>` section, add `<globalization culture="en-AU" uiCulture="en-AU" />` (or what ever culture you want)

Comment: thanks! that did the trick. Although for asp core I needed to set the cultureInfo in the Startup file. you may post your comment as answer and I tick it as my answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the culture of your server to one that accepts dates in `dd/MM/yyyy` format.

To set the default culture in your `startup.cs` file, in the `ConfigureServices` method (note the following sets the culture to `en-AU` (Australia))

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-AU");
    });
    services.AddMvc();
}
```

and in the `Configure` method

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    app.UseRequestLocalization();
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<input class="form-control datepicker" name="DateOfBirth" type="text" required data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
```

You must use date-date-format:"dd-mm-yyyy"